# Dos niveles de logger Java

Tags: java, log4j, logger

```
 # Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, stdout

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\logging.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Tengo el siguiente fichero properties para el logger, y funciona correctamente. Mi duda es como podria dividir la salida en base a la salida por consola y fichero. Es decir:

Mi intención es que lo que salga en consola sea a nivel de INFO y lo que añade al fichero a nivel de TRACE

Versionado del POM

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Los *appenders* tienen una propiedad *Threshold* que permite definir el nivel de log correspondiente para cada appender.

```
log4j.appender.file.level=TRACE
```

Lo que ya no tengo claro es la correlación con el nivel de log definido en el *logger* (es decir, si se aplicarán los dos filtros o solo el que definas en el *appender*); se pueden hacer pruebas pero lo más seguro es poner en el *logger* el nivel más bajo al que quieras hacer log (*TRACE*) y dejar que cada *appender* haga su propio filtro.

```
log4j.rootLogger=TRACE, file, stdout

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.stdout.Threshold=INFO

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\logging.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.file.Threshold=TRACE
```

Comment: Probé lo siguiente pero en la consola me salia a nivel de trace y en el fichero tambien. Seguire mirando, gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué versión de log4j usas?

Comment: Actualice la pregunta

Comment: Parece que me confundí con la propiedad, no debería ser *level* sino *Threshold* https://coderanch.com/t/63324/open-source/set-loglevel-log

Comment: Perfecto funciona. Actualiza la respuesta si quieres para futuras consultas. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

No sé si será el caso, pero yo he solucionado un problema similar usando la opción log4j.additivity.

```
log4j.appender.stdout.additivity=false
log4j.appender.file.additivity=false
```

En concreto, lo que hace el flag additivity es evitar que los mensaje de un logger se propagen, con lo que solo deberían de mostrarse en el appender correspondiente.

Comment: Gracias por el aporte !!